# How to clear NHibernate cache after exceptions

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate

I'm wondering how to best handle the "problem" of NHibernate caching objects known to be in a bad state.

Made a small, stupid, example to illustrate the problem I am having.

```
public void RepaintCar(ISession session, int carId, System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    try
    {
         session.BeginTransaction();
         var car = session.Query<Car>().First(x => x.Id == carId);
         car.FrontColor = color;
         throw new Exception("Ran out of Paint. Could not finish job!");
         car.BackColor = color;
         session.SaveOrUpdate(car); 
         session.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         session.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}  
public void StartCar(ISession session, int carId)
{
    session.BeginTransaction();
    var car = session.Query<Car>().First(x => x.Id == carId);
    car.Start();
    session.SaveOrUpdate(car);
    session.Transaction.Commit();
}
public void TestScenario()
{
    var session = SessionFactory.GetSession();
    try
    {
        RepaintCar(session, 1, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // lets ignore the exception, we probably just ran out of paint
    }
    StartCar(session, 1);
}
```

Now, if we run the TestScenario, we would obviously get an exception and the Save&Commit would not occur. Fine. But! In StartCar we will get the cached Car object that has gotten the FrontColor changed. The car that is saved will be a car having different colors for Front and Back!

What is the best way to avoid this behaviour? I know that I could make a session.Clear() when an transaction rollback occurs. Is this the best way to avoid this kind of more or less unpredictable behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new session!

From the [docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#manipulatingdata-exceptions)

> If the ISession throws an exception you should immediately rollback
>   the transaction, call ISession.Close() and discard the ISession
>   instance.

Comment: Yes, that is if you get an exception within your ISession. This problem is if you get any kind of exception, not having to do with the session at all.

Comment: @user3415594 So, that's not really an NHibernate question, then.  You'd have the same issue even if you were just dealing with in-memory objects.